# Ads in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, ads

I have published 3 apps in windows phone marketplace.I added ad control to each app and added client id and app id from pubcenter to apps.But ads are not displayed in any of my apps.What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did it work in your emulator/developer device? I had the same problem, where nothing appeared. Did you enable the following Capabilities:

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
```

All of them are needed for advertising.

Comment: All the above capabilities are added to app.It doesnot work even in emulator.